# ECG wave form in android application

Tags: java, javascript, android, signal-processing

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of ECG signals on an android mobile phone.

I am deciding if I should make my own signal processing library for android or not because I can't seem to find any online.

Does anybody know of a library that I can use or would it be easier and faster to make my own?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by processing? analyzing or plotting?

Comment: plotting the ecg wave form in android application

Answer (score 0):

I used AndroidPlot for plotting ECG signals in real-time. The sensors I used was a 4 lead ECG which could provide RL and LL through Bluetooth. Here's the sample for the plotting but, feel free to modify it to your need. And if the recent AndroidPlot doesn't support any of the methods used here please research it and change it. And finally this method is not efficient since, it keeps redrawing plot, I believe AndroidPlot supports better implementation in new versions :

This is how you define the plot in XML:

```
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
android:id="@+id/ecgSPlot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
title="ECG History" />
```

And this is the code to plot it:

```
 public static XYPlot ecgHistoryPlot = null; 
 public static SimpleXYSeries ecgLevelsSeries = new SimpleXYSeries( 
        "ECG History");

private static LinkedList<Integer> ecgRaLlHistory = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
private static LinkedList<Integer> ecgLaLlHistory = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 

/**
 * This method will set plot paramaters including look and label 
 */
private void setMergedPlotParam() { 
    ecgHistoryPlot = (XYPlot) viewRTPlotting.findViewById(R.id.ecgSPlot); 
    ecgHistoryPlot 
        .setRangeBoundaries(-180, 359, XYPlot.BoundaryMode.FIXED); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 60, XYPlot.BoundaryMode.FIXED); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.addSeries(ecgRaLlHistorySeries, 
        LineAndPointRenderer.class, 
        new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255), Color.BLACK)); 

    ecgHistoryPlot.addSeries(ecgLaLlHistorySeries, 
        LineAndPointRenderer.class, 
        new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0), Color.BLACK)); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.setDomainStepValue(5); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.setDomainLabel("Time"); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().pack(); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.setRangeLabel("Level"); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.getRangeLabelWidget().pack(); 
    ecgHistoryPlot.disableAllMarkup(); 
} 

/**
 * This method will update plot data
 */
private static void drawMergedPlot(int EcgRaLl, int EcgLaLl) { 
    Number[] seriesRNumbers = { EcgRaLl, EcgLaLl }; 
    ecgLevelsSeries.setModel(Arrays.asList(seriesRNumbers), 
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED); 

    if (ecgRaLlHistory.size() > HISTORY_SIZE 
        || ecgLaLlHistory.size() > HISTORY_SIZE) { 
        ecgRaLlHistory.removeFirst(); 
        ecgLaLlHistory.removeFirst(); 
    } 

    ecgRaLlHistory.addLast(EcgRaLl); 
    ecgLaLlHistory.addLast(EcgLaLl); 

    ecgRaLlHistorySeries.setModel(ecgRaLlHistory, 
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY); 
    ecgLaLlHistorySeries.setModel(ecgLaLlHistory, 
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY); 
    ecgSHistoryPlot.redraw(); 
} 

/**
* This method should be called when there's new data.
*/
private static void onSensorReading(int EcgRaLl, int EcgLaLl) { 
    drawMergedPlot(EcgRaLl, EcgLaLl); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.Your ecg sensor gave what kind of output?

Comment: The payload consisted the sensor boilerplate version, GPS, Accel and Gyro. I had configured my sensor to provide only ECG. And as you can see the code, it contained 2 floats.

Comment: i am using pulse sensor to get the ecg output , it will giva a analog signal, analog signal converted into digital signal and send it via bluetooth to the phone-any suggestios plsss

Comment: can u please sent the full details about your project.plssss
selvadinesh8@gmail.com